# C - finding the frequency of elements fails with number 0

Tags: c, arrays

I want to count the frequency of each and every element in the array and print it but I don't want to count the number which I have already counted.

below is my code

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, n, f = 0, count = 1;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(a[i] == a[j] && a[j] != '\0')
            {
                f = 1;
                count++;
                a[j] = '\0';
            }
        }

        if(f == 1)
            printf("%d %d\n", a[i], count);
        else if(a[i] != '\0')
            printf("%d %d\n", a[i], count);

        count = 1 ; 
        f = 0;
    }
}
```

my output is failing when I am taking input as `0`. For example, suppose
my input consists of eight values as

```
7 5 6 7 3 0 5 0
```

for the above input, I do not get the frequency for `0` but for the rest of the elements I am getting the frequency as

```
7 2                                                                                                                              
5 2                                                                                                                              
6 1                                                                                                                              
3 1
```

but for `0` why I am not getting the frequency?
how to rectify this?

Comment: `[j]!='\0'` is the culprit, it means value zero. These inputer are not taken as strings but integers, so you shouldn't be checking for `\0`. Neither should you null terminate the array. There should be no need for a sentinel value as you know the array size.

Comment: @Lundin yeah i got the problem but how to rectify that one do u have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code doesn't work for zeros is that you are not counting the elements with '\0' {`if(a[i]==a[j]&&a[j]!='\0')`}
 
But ascii value of NULL i.e, '\0' is 0 [(http://www.asciitable.com)](http://www.asciitable.com) hence you are not counting for the zeroes and also not displaying anything.

Instead of keeping '\0' for those which you visited keep a negative number( if you dont use it).

Comment: one solution is to find the frequency of zeroes before you start your for loop, it may seem silly but it works for sure, but the order of occurrence will not be the same. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CKw0.png)

Comment: occurrence order is to be also taken care.bro

Comment: I got one more solution which has one bit space overhead for every integer.
You can store the information of the node being visited in a boolean variable. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcXUE.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(a[i]==a[j]&&a[j]!='\0')
        {
            f=1;
            count++;
            a[j]='\0';
```

a[] is integer and you are storing character '\0' which converted in 0.

To solve this problem, you have to first count number of zeros then count others number.